# npm often stuck showing `node-pre-gyp` and `node install`

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, node-pre-gyp

When trying to install various npm packages (e.g. the Vue CLI: `npm i @vue/cli`), the installation hangs and I get the following warning:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
```

I tried installing `nvm` and installing the latest Node (v13.1.0), which didn't help.

I then did Ctrl+C, and tried `npm i @vue/cli --verbose`. This worked fine, but then when running `vue create vue-test`, after "Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...", I get:

```
> fsevents@1.2.9 install /Users/liranharary/dev/playground/vue-test/node_modules/fsevents
> node install
```

Can anyone advise why this is happening and how to fix it?

I'm using a 2019 MacBook Pro with MacOS Catalina version 10.15.1

Comment: According to [this post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3402) someone was able to solve the issue with `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, I'm running into the same issue: (`fsevents... node install...`)